# Regular expression for fractional street address

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regular expression to match the fractional portion of a street address (e.g. 123 1/2 Broadway). This is what I have:

`(?<=\d+ )\d/\d`

So basically match any string `x/x` that follows any number of digits and a space. For some reason I don't get any matches. If I remove the plus this works okay:

`(?<=\d )\d/\d`

... but I still don't understand why the first one wouldn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? Some of them don't support variable length look-behinds.

Comment: Yes, please be more explicit about context. RegEx engine, programming language / command line utility. Code segment in the first case, exact command and options in the second, etc.

Comment: Sorry about that - this will be in JavaScript but at the moment I'm just using the search function in Sublime Text to test it out.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support lookbehind at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your regex engine, the characters in your lookbehind have to be of fixed width. Since `\d+` is not fixed width (`+` means it can be 1, 2, 3, etc times), it won't work.

As for why, I think that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3797290/1578604) answers it well :)