# regexp - Match whole string if it doesn't contain another string

Tags: regex-lookarounds, regex

What I need to do is to get the whole input string, if it doesn't contain another string.

To be more clear (php code, doesn't really matter, the regexp is important):

Let's say the string we want to negate is "home".

```
 preg_match($unknownReg, "This is a home bla bla", $part);
 echo $part; // I need to echo "";

 preg_match($unknownReg, "This is a car", $part);
 echo $part; // I need to echo "This is a car"
```

I'm aware of solutions like strpos (for php), but I'd like a reg for it (because not knowing it burns be from inside :)) ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this pattern:

```
^.*(?<!home.*)$
```

Or this one:

```
^(?!.*home).*$
```

Both patterns will match any sequence of characters as long as it doesn't contain `home` anywhere in the string. For example:

```php
"This is a home bla bla" // no match
"This is a car"          // match
```

You can test the second pattern [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28?!.%2ahome%29.%2a%24&input=%22This%20is%20a%20home%20bla%20bla%22%0A%22This%20is%20a%20car%22).

Comment: That <b>looks</b> ok, but I get this: Compilation failed: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length. 
Second one is ok, so +1 + accept. I'll break down the first later.

Comment: @zozo I tested it in C#, but it really *does* matter what engine you use.

Comment: @zozo For more information on this error, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3797290/1715579

Answer (score 0):

Pure negation? To be or !(to be):

```php
!preg_match("#home#", "This is a home bla bla", $part);
```