# Perl global substitution with look ahead and look behind?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I am trying to perform a global substitution in perl on a string on a basis of a certain pattern NOT matching before or after a certain match. Basically, I have an xml tag and want to keep it if a match occurs within ten characters before or after the tag, but remove the xml tag if not.

so, if I have a string which contains:

```
foo something<xml tag>bar<\xml tag> something
```

No substitution will occur, but if a string is

```
something <xml tag>bar<\xml tag> something
```

it would be replaced with:

```
something bar something
```

What I tried is:

```
$string =~ s/(?<!foo.{0,10})<xml tag>(bar)<\/xml tag> |<xml tag>(bar)<\/xml tag>(?!.{0,10}foo)/$1/g;
```

But I got this error:

```
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex
```

I'm not really sure how to do this. Help?

Comment: Look behinds in regex have to be fixed length: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796436/whats-the-technical-reason-for-lookbehind-assertion-must-be-fixed-length-in-r

Answer (score 0):

From **perlretut**:

> Lookahead "(?=regexp)" can match arbitrary regexps, but lookbehind
>   "(?<=fixed-regexp)" only works for regexps of fixed width, i.e., a
>   fixed number of characters long.  Thus "(?<=(ab|bc))" is fine, but
>   "(?<=(ab)*)" is not.

So if the word(s) have fixed length before `<xml tag>bar<\xml tag>` you should use it otherwise you may use more than one regexps for example.

Answer (score 0):

One way using the `e` flag:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    s/((.{0,13})<xml\ tag>([^<]*)<\/xml\ tag>)(?!.{0,10}foo)/
    index($2,'foo') > -1 ? "$1" : "$2$3"/xe;
    print $_; 
}

__DATA__
foo something<xml tag>bar</xml tag> something
something <xml tag>bar</xml tag> something
```

Produces:

```
foo something<xml tag>bar</xml tag> something
something bar something
```