# Get all words that have not a specific prefix group

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of the following form

```
$string = "This is {test} for [a]{test2} for {test3}.";
```

I want to get all curly brackets that are not prefixed by square brackets. Thus, in the above string I would like to get `{test}` and `{test3}` but not `[a]{test2}`.

I found in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/977294/2311074 that this might be possible with negative lookahead. So I tried

```
  $regex      = '/(?:(?!\[[^\}]+\])\{[^\}]+\})/';
  echo preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches) . '<br>';
  print_r($matches);
```

but this still gives me all three curly brackets.

> 3
>
> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => {test} [1] => {test2} [2] => {test3} )
> )

Why is this not working?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for your detailed answer. I am catching up on the topic negative lookahead. I will respond / upvote your answer as soon as I have understood it.

Comment: Please ask what is unclear right away - I will be online for some hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your regex fails is that it matches any `{` (followed with 1+ non-`}`s and then a `}`) if it does not start a sequence of the patterns inside the negative lookahead, a `[`, 1+ chars other than `}` and then a `]` (and it is always true, so, you get all `{...}` substrings as a result).

Use [`(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex):

```
\[[^]]*]\{[^}]+}(*SKIP)(*F)|\{[^\}]+}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z32uIr/1/).

**Details**:

- `\[[^]]*]\{[^}]+}(*SKIP)(*F)` - matches

  - `\[` - a `[`
  - `[^]]*`  - 0+ chars other than `]`
  - `]\{` - `]{` substring
  - `[^}]+` - 1+ chars other than `]`
  - `}`  - a literal `}`
  - `(*SKIP)(*F)` - PCRE verbs discarding the text matched so far and forcing the engine to go on looking for the next match from the current position (as if a match occurred)
- `|` - or
- `\{[^\}]+}`:

  - `\{` - a `{`
  - `[^\}]+` - 1+ chars other than `}` and
  - `}` - a literal `}`.

See the  [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/MP5yN0):

```
$string = "This is {test} for [a]{test2} for {test3}.";
$regex      = '/\[[^]]*]\{[^}]+}(*SKIP)(*F)|\{[^}]+}/';
echo preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches) . "\n";
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
2
Array
(
    [0] => {test}
    [1] => {test3}
)
```

Comment: Thank you. I just realized that I had a mistake in my rexgex, I actually wanted to use `'/(?<!\[[^\}]+\])\{[^\}]+\}/'` but this doesn't work because of **“lookbehind assertion MUST be fixed length”** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796436/whats-the-technical-reason-for-lookbehind-assertion-must-be-fixed-length-in-r. So here it makes sense to use your skip fail method, instead of going backwards. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is the only correct way to negate something in PCRE having no access to a negative infinite width lookbehind without making assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure opening curly braces would only be preceded with a pair of square brackets (balanced) then a negative lookbehind will do the job:

```
(?<!]){[^}]*}
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/yxwPfy/1)

Comment: Very nice hint, thanks :)! Is it not necessary to escape `]`and `}` ?