# Using str_match with lookbehind (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT)

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to use regex to extract a string, it works here: https://regexr.com/3vsd4

But when running something similar in R it fails:

```
m =  "(?<=~* )([ AP_])\\w+"
x = "XY_O ~ R_Z + YPP_L_WINTER + AP_C"
str_match(x, m)[1, 1]
```

Gives the error:

> Error in stri_match_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) : 
>   Look-Behind pattern matches must have a bounded maximum length. (U_REGEX_LOOK_BEHIND_LIMIT)

How can I edit the `R` code to return `"AP_C"`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the technical reason for "lookbehind assertion MUST be fixed length" in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796436/whats-the-technical-reason-for-lookbehind-assertion-must-be-fixed-length-in-r)

Comment: Well, your `~*` is not bounded. You could change to `~{0, 100}  {0, 100}`, but those won't help narrow anything down, if zero repetitions are a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies that the goal of your code is to match `AP_C`. If that is the case, lookbehind should not be required. You can just pull out the matched subpattern from your call to str_match.

Without knowing all of the possible formats of your strings, something like this should work for the example you provided:

```
m = "~.*? (AP_\\w+)"
x = "XY_O ~ R_Z + YPP_L_WINTER + AP_C"
str_match(x, m)[1, 1]
```

There are probably other regex possibilities depending on your format requirements.

Comment: this returns `"~ R_Z + YPP_L_WINTER + AP_C"`