# match word that contains "XYZ" and does not start with colon

Tags: php, regex, utf-8

I am looking for a regex pattern that matches any word that contains `XYZ` and does not start with a colon `:`.

For example, I would like to match from `This isXYZ a :exampleXYZa` only `isXYZ`.

My first idea was to use this regex pattern:

```
/(?<!\:[^\s\r\t\n])XYZ/
```

Basically, a negative lookbehind to assure that there is no colon without whitespace beforehand. However, this does not work, because [lookbehind assertion must be fixed length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3797290/2311074).

EDIT: I would also like to have utf8 support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a regex like below:

```
/\b((?<!:)\w*XYZ\w*)\b/ui
```

- `\b` before and after is to just match a word boundary.
- In `((?<!:)\w*XYZ\w*)`, we check for any word that has `XYZ` in it and has zero or more characters before it and zero or more characters after it. With the help of negative lookbehind `(?<!:)`, we make sure that it is not preceded by a `:`.
- As mentioned by **@unclexo** in the comments, you can add the `u` modifier at the end to support UTF-8 sequence matching. [See here for more info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).
- You can also add the `i` flag for case insensitive matching.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$tests = [
        'This isXYZ a :exampleXYZa',
        'isXYZ a :exampleXYZa abcXYZ',
        'isXYZ a :exampleXYZXYZa  abcXYZ',
        'XYZ',
        'XYZjdhf',
        'This isXYZ a example:XYZa',
        'äöüéèXYZ :äöüéèXYZäöüéè'
    ];

foreach($tests as $test){
    if(preg_match_all('/\b((?<!:)\w*XYZ\w*)\b/ui',$test,$matches)){
        print_r($matches[0]);
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/Y8SMj

Comment: @Nick Nice catch. I am assuming it shouldn't match, but let's see what OP considers it to be.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The downsite of using `\b` is that  `\b` matches only the position between an ascii char and a non-ascii char. This means umlaute like `äöüéè` and many others are not supported. For example with `This isäXYZ` he would only find `XYZ` and not `isäXYZ`.

Comment: @Adam It should work if you add `u` flag at the end of the pattern.

Comment: @Adam Updated my answer. Seems to work fine with `This isäXYZ` too.

Comment: @Adam you should now select the answer. Thanks