# Can a regular expression in GeSHi include a keyword?

Tags: regex, parsing, keyword, geshi

I'm working on a language file for [GeSHi](https://github.com/GeSHi/geshi-1.0) and would like to highlight the (unknown) word following a keyword and some whitespace. I have tried something like

```
$language_data = array (
    ...
    'KEYWORDS' => array(
        1 => array(
            'keyword1', 'keyword2'
            )
        ),
    ...
    'REGEXPS' => array(
        0 => array(
            GESHI_SEARCH => '(((keyword1|keyword2)\s+)([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))',
            GESHI_REPLACE => '\\4',
            GESHI_MODIFIERS => '',
            GESHI_BEFORE => '\\2',
            GESHI_AFTER => ''
            )
        ),
    ...
)
```

But the regular expression never matches. I assume that the keyword is already consumed by the parser when the regular expression is tested.

A lookbehind does not work in `GESHI_SEARCH` because the length of the real keywords and the separating whitespace is not fixed (see [What's the technical reason for "lookbehind assertion MUST be fixed length" in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796436/whats-the-technical-reason-for-lookbehind-assertion-must-be-fixed-length-in-r)).

How can I highlight a word after a keyword in GeSHi?

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/SLzJ77/1

GeSHi\s*([\w]+) use this regex (may work)

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how your suggestion relates to my question. Could you explain a little, please?